# How to encode video base64 with ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I am using the `cordova-plugin-media-capture` for a video and then encode it in `base64` to send to an `AWS` web service from an application on **ionic+ angularjs**.

what do you recommend?

```
$scope.captureVideo = function() {

    var options = {  duration: 5 };

    $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
        alert('1videoData ' + videoData[0].fullPath);
        alert('1videoData ' + videoData[0].localURL);


    }
}
```

Comment: Hey have you found the solution?\

Comment: I did not continue with this idea because the videos in base64 consume a lot of memory and slow the app